# Why POST request from Unity return empty in php?

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine, post

I want to create Register and Login in my game, i created a simple database, and post request from off documentation by Unity. But in php $_POST['any'] always return empty.

I try with $_GET['any'], and it work, but need to use POST.

This is c# code:

```
 private IEnumerator IESignUp()
{
    List<IMultipartFormSection> formData = new List<IMultipartFormSection>();
    formData.Add(new MultipartFormDataSection("username=username&password=12345678"));
    //string.Format("username={0}&password={1}", usernameInput.text, passwordInput.text)
    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("http://multiplayer_game:8080/sing_up.php", formData);
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
    {
        popupWindow.Show("Network not respond!", www.error, PopupWindow.Type.Error);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");
    }
}
```

And this is php code:

```
  if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
$sql = "INSERT INTO players (username, password, mail, points, serrviums, skin_id, weapon_id, inventory) VALUES ('".$_POST['username']."', '".$_POST['password']."', 'test@mail.ru', 0, 0, 0, 0, '0|0')";

if(mysqli_query($connection, $sql))
    echo 'Successful';
else
    echo 'Error';
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use WWWForm as suggested in the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Post.html):

```
WWWForm formData = new WWWForm();
formData.AddField("username", "username");
formData.AddField("password", "12345678");
```

---

Also don’t forget to use HTTPS instead for sending/receiving user data, especially login credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Your php file is sing_up.php -- not sign_up.php?
I've been foiled by worse.